# Getting all the rows even though they are not mapped in Dimension usage

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I have a fact table that can store 2 types of transactions - TrxType1, TrxType2 having an attribute called Owner_Id mapped to Dim Owner. Problem is only one type of transaction TrxType1 has owner and the other does not have a relationship. Hence while querying the cube I am not getting the records for TrxType2.

Is there a way to manage it? I have already tried changing Null Processing to UnkownMember but still I am unable to see.

Answer (score 0):

In my practice I always fill in dictionary tables with None value and map to this member all blank values. 
But if you don't have any transactions with type TrxType2 how you can count them?

If you have next fact table:

```
Type_Id             Owner_id                ...
__________________________________________
1                13 (just for example)
1                8
0                11
0                4

Dictionary TrxType:
___________________________
id           Code
0            None
1            TrxType1
2            TrxType2
```

your dimension can have the following hierarchy

```
                        Count of rows 
All                     4
  -None                 2  
  -TrxType1             2
  -TrxType2             0
```

If you have different situation - please write an example.

Comment: I think this is how its supposed to be.

Comment: hi max, your are indeed right. It is indeed a good practice to implement this scenario. For my particular case, in the DimTrxType, Id column UnknownMember was set to hidden and now I made it visible and hence the code is working fine. My question now is how does one populate unknown? I mean to say initially while loading data from a file to Prod db, we take the values from repository and fill the Dimensions in which case we do not have any uknown. Do you mean to say we would need to run a script and insert a value of unkown when the system is first set-up?

Comment: Hello, I do it in two ways.
1) Scripts for ETL-process. We are mapping all data in the fact table (for all fields, on that we need to have dimensions) using left joins with ISNULL(sth,0)-statement. Before that all dictionaries MUST be updated from new data.
So all values which don't have corresponding value in the dictionary
will have ID=0.
2)In the Data Source View of your olap db. You can add calculated field to your fact table and write some sql-expression to fill this calculated ID-field. After that you have to use this new field for your attribute (in the corresponding dimension).

Comment: Sorry for my English. I hope it will help you.